# How we do we programmatically detect locks on folders in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I have an application that fails to delete a directory.  Usually this is due to an unintended lock on that directory.  We need the application to detect and report what processes currently have a lock on that directory.

I have attempted to use RestartManager's API to detect these locks. It works fine for files, but cannot detect locks on folders.

I see that ProcessExplorer can report what processes are using a directory.  We desparately need this capability to be embedded in our application. How do we accomplish this?

Comment: Have you searched the MSDN sites for "c++ folder properties lock"?